# How to modify confirmation dialog in Rails when I have webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

My current file looks like this, but when I added webpacker gem this no longer works. How can this be accomplished now?

I tried using `Rails` instead of `$.rails` and that did not work.

```
var allowAction = function (link) {
  if (!link.attr('data-confirm')) {
    return true;
  }
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link);
  return false;
};

$.rails.handleConfirm = function(e) {
  if (!allowAction(this)) {
    return stopEverything(e);
  }
};

$.rails.confirmed = function (link) {
  link.removeAttr('data-confirm');
  return link.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function (link) {
  var html, message, title;
  message = link.attr('data-confirm');
  title = link.attr('data-title');
  html =
    '<div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog" data-test="confirmation-modal">\n' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog" data-fe="modal-dialog">\n ' +
    '<div class="modal-content" data-fe="modal-content">\n ' +
    '<button data-fe="x-close-button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">\n</button>  ' +
    '<div class="modal-header">\n    ' +
    '<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>\n    ' +
    '<h4 class="modal-title">' + title + '</h4>\n  </div>\n  ' +
    '<div class="modal-body">\n    <p>' + message + '</p>\n  </div>\n  ' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">\n    ' +
    '<a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>\n    ' +
    '<a data-dismiss="modal" data-fe="confirm-button" class="btn btn-primary confirm">OK</a>\n  ' +
    '</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>';
  $(html).modal();
  return $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').click(function () {
    return $.rails.confirmed(link);
  });
};
```

Comment: It would help if you provide more details on what error you get and your rest of the rails setup that compiles your javascript

Comment: I get no error, the standard browser confirmation box shows up instead of the one with the styling changes I have added.